# Cannot pass props to React Router page component, TS2322

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, tsc

I’m fighting the typescript compiler trying to expect props in an exported component that is rendered as a React Router page. (I am using the newest version of `react-router-dom`, 5.2.0.

In my library code:

```
interface AppProps {
    baseApiUrl?: string
}
export function App({
    baseApiUrl = ''
}: AppProps): React.ReactElement<AppProps> { /* my component code */ }
```

In the implementation code where I'm seeing the typescript error:

```
export function Sandbox(): React.ReactElement {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="*">
                    <App baseApiUrl="http://localhost:3000"  />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

Why is it that I am getting this typescript error?

```
TS2322: Type '{ baseApiUrl: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & AppProps'.
  Property 'baseApiUrl' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & AppProps'.
     8 |            <Switch>
     9 |                <Route path="*">
  > 10 |                    <App baseApiUrl="http://localhost:3000"  />
       |                         ^^^^^^^^^^
    11 |                </Route>
    12 |            </Switch>
    13 |        </BrowserRouter>
```

Where is this IntrinsicAttributes coming from? What can I do to make the compiler happy?

I've already tried to rewrite the function signature like this:

```
export const App: React.FC<AppProps> = (props) => { /* my component code */ }
```

and got the same compiler error.

Comment: Why not render `App` on the `render` or `component` prop so `history` is passed as a prop (via route props), or use the `useHistory` React hook to access `history` from the routing context?

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I edited away any `history` passing and used the `useHistory` instead, unfortunately the compiler still doesn't like it. I edited the post to reflect those changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer you don't need to do anything to make the compiler happy.

As you can see at https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-wood-5clyq?file=/src/App.tsx the code you shared is fine, so there must be some other code broken somehow. For example you have two things both called AppProps, and the one that generates the error is different than the one you shared. Given you didn't share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's only a guess.

Perhaps you could make a reproducible example by forking the sandbox I shared above?

[image]

Comment: You're right. I put this in a codesandbox myself and didn't see the error. It has to do with something in my development environment.